# math mode in titles doesn't match font

Tags: math-mode, typography

When typesetting math in a section title, it will be set in italic serif normal, just as usual. The surrounding text however will be (depending on the documentclass) sans bold which looks like a blatant mismatch:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{Surface of a unit $n-1$-sphere}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it possible to math typeset in sans bold in titles?

Comment: it might be if you have the fonts, customise your section headings to use `\boldmath` when setting up the section font. Note some math journals (certainly AMS ones) never change the fonts for math in headings as it could potentially change the meaning

Comment: Probably a stupid question but if you want it in sans bold, why don't you omit the math mode ($) in the paragraph title at all?

Comment: ` sansmath` defines a `\mathversion{sans}`. However, it won't be bold + slanted. Do you need it only for a casual use with very simple formulæ as the above?

Comment: @Bernard I'd love to see a general solution, but can't probably expect one. Something is better than nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Best option name in history:

```latex
\documentclass[
  egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles
]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Surface of a unit $n-1$-sphere}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is fantastic to know the english language. :-(

Comment: For koma  v3.39 or newer there is now the class option `sfdefaults=false` instead of `egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles`

Answer (score 1):

Create a bold sans-serif math version, e.g. `sansbold`, and add `\mathversion{sansbold}` to the formatting of your headings.

In traditional NFSS, you would `\DeclareMathVersion{sansbold}`, followed by `\SetSymbolFont` for each 8-bit legacy math font.  This must have the same encoding as your regular math font.  The `newtxsf` fonts might work with `newtxmath` or `newpxmath`, or you might swap around the `letters` alphabet from `stix` or `stix2` with the `operators` from the bold font.

With `unicode-math`, you declare this font with `\setmathfont[version=boldsans]{SomeFont.otf}`.  Unfortunately, as of 2020, the only free bold math fonts are XITS Math and Libertinus Math and the only free sans-serif math font is Fira Math.  You could, if you’re desperate, use something like `\setmathfont[version=boldsans, FakeBold = 1.2, Scale=MatchLowercase]{Fira Math}`.